# WebBrowser control not launching webpage

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

Please see the code below:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Threading

Public Class clsLoadWebpageBehindScenes
    Private boolDocumentCompleted As Boolean
    ' Private intTest As Integer

    Private Sub WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        Try
            Dim BrowsePage As WebBrowser = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser)
            'BrowsePage.ClientSize = New Size(BrowsePage.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width, BrowsePage.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height)
            BrowsePage.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
            BrowsePage.ScrollBarsEnabled = True
            BrowsePage.BringToFront()
            'compressImage(ConvertedImage)
            'MsgBox("Test")
            boolDocumentCompleted = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox("Test")
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadPage()
        'Me.PageUrl = PageUrl
        Dim thrCurrent As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf BrowsePage))
        thrCurrent.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        thrCurrent.Start()
        thrCurrent.Join()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BrowsePage()
        Try
            Dim BrowsePage As New WebBrowser()
            BrowsePage.ScrollBarsEnabled = False
            AddHandler BrowsePage.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf _
    WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted
            BrowsePage.ScrollBarsEnabled = True
            BrowsePage.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = False
            'BrowsePage.DocumentText = "http://pcname/app/TestWebBrowser.aspx"
            BrowsePage.Navigate("http://pcname/app/TestWebBrowser.aspx")
            While boolDocumentCompleted = False
                'intTest = intTest + 1
                'While BrowsePage.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
                Application.DoEvents()
            End While
            BrowsePage.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have a windows forms app, which is calling: `LoadPage()`

As far as I am concerned; the following webpage should be called:

http://pcname/app/TestWebBrowser.aspx.  However, this is not happening.  I have added `Thread.Sleep(30000)` to the webpage, however WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted is instantly reached (it should take at least 30 seconds because of the `Thread.Sleep(30000)`.  What is wrong with the code?

Comment: I have come up with a new rule for VB programming: if you have the need to call Thread.sleep() in your code, you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As for your browser not loading the page at startup, if all the code your presenting is the only code in your project than your missing the sub to launch at program load, for example changing `Public Sub LoadPage()` to `Public Sub LoadPage(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load` should handle the not loading at startup problem, but its also not the only problem present that i can see, when using multiple threads you cannot simply call .Navigate directly from another thread without Invoking it, (*See examples here at:* [Microsoft Thread-Safe Calls to Form Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx)) or an easier route would be to just remove the seperate thread for the browser since a lot of places ive looked while attempting to use browsers on some of my projects i saw this:

> Webbrowsers are by default asynchronous so you don't need to thread them.

Also this Line Here: `Dim BrowsePage As New WebBrowser()` Your creating a new Browser Control but your not Adding it to the form with `Me.Controls.Add(BrowsePage)`... Last thing i can think of that would be a little more of advice would be That its Best not to Dim a Variable / Control to be the same name as a Sub looking through i noticed you did that `Private Sub BrowsePage()` & `Dim BrowsePage As New WebBrowser()` would be best to make them two different names that way you dont confuse yourself when writing code and accidentally use the sub when you mean to use the variable.